# Using ProGuard with the D8 DEX compiler is no longer supported

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile-application

Using visual studio 2022 with Xamarin I am following the steps to prepare and reduce the size of my app for publishing

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard

So selecting ProGuard from Code Shrinker dropdown When I rebuild the app, I get the following error:

***"Using ProGuard with the D8 DEX compiler is no longer supported. Please set the code shrinker to 'r8' in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'AndroidLinkTool' MSBuild property to 'r8'."***

Seeing this error ***"Using ProGuard with the D8 DEX compiler is no longer supported"*** I tried to find another option but in Dex Compiler dropdown there is no other option rather than d8 and dex.
If I set the dex compiler to dx, I get the following:

***"Using the DX DEX Compiler is not supported. Please set the DEX compiler to 'd8' in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'AndroidDexTool' MSBuild property to 'd8'."***

So now my question is how do I enable ProGuard Shrinker option in my app.
I am using visual studio 2022 and android version is 13.0

Answer (score 0):

As the text clearly says you need to change the Code shrinker option to r8 (or nothing) - that is currently set to ProGuard.

You are changing the wrong option.

Comment: Using the option r8 the app size is not reduced. I also read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker. And using the linker option "Link SDK Assemblies" the app size is stay the same like the "none" option my simple hello world app size is always 25mb. How can I reduce the app size?

Comment: And also when I build the app the output window shows this warning "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt : warning XA4304: ProGuard configuration file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt' was not found." I also don't find the Android folder in my system. I installed the android sdk using visual studio as it is said in this tuitorial https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/xamarin/hello-world-tutorial/create.

Comment: @UdinM you already reduce app size with linker, that is primary source of reduction for C# apps. It is expected that ProGuard won’t have huge or any effect on C# apps. This is for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Code shrinker option to r8, try to use [Customizing ProGuard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows#customizing-proguard) to keep some classes. For example: `-keep public class xxx`. This can effectively reduce the size of the APP.